# Substitute for F*** in emphasizing disbelief, anger, etc

Tags: offensive-language, minced-oaths, euphemisms

How do I replace F*** while expressing fully my disbelief, anger, etc?

E.g.,

"I think Homer Simpson is incredibly sexy"

My reply "Get out of here! That's f***ing ridiculous."

Comment: I would suggest “Fuck”. It makes a great substitute to “F***” for people allergic to asterisks.

Comment: @F'x Nailed it. Just a joke -> I suppose the apostrophe in your user-name is a substitute for 'u'? ;P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the most obvious choice would be [*freaking*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/freaking) or [*effing*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effing).

Comment: You are right. I probably choose your answer as the right one. But I guess I am going to leave this open for a while in case someone offers a creative and funny one. I once heard someone use "Bull Funky" to replace Bulls***. That was funny.

Comment: There are quite a few euphemisms of varying degrees of vulgarity and funniness. If you just follow either link and look under "Synonyms", you will find *flaming*, *flipping*, *fricking* — and that's only the tip of the iceberg, if you ask me. It's just that *freaking* is the most obvious choice, most likely to be understood by Americans, Brits, and non-native speakers alike. I don't think the same is true of, say, *flaming* (seems to be a UK thing) or even *effing* (might leave non-native speakers scratching their heads).

Comment: Yes I did follow the link for freaking. I like blooming. I am partial to the UK euphemisms.

Comment: @keisimone: Are you sure you don't mean [bullpucky](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bullpucky)?

Comment: @psmears No I really meant [bull funky](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bull+funky) Hah.. I am laughing again with tears down my cheek

Answer (score 6):

Besides RegDwight’s excellent suggestions, **flaming** and **frigging** are both widely used (respectively more common in the UK and US, I think).

In my family, when I was small, my father would always say “That’s ff… *frankly* ridiculous,” and so on — going completely over my head at the time, and much to the amusement of the adults around.  “Shiver me timbers!” was another favourite exclamation of his, for similar reasons…

It’s easy to vary the subtlety/blatantness of these, and hence to sound completely innocuous to outsiders while ensuring that your friends know what you’re *really* thinking :-)

Comment: I like Shiver me Timbers!!

Comment: "Freaking" is also a common one.

Comment: "Fracking" is my favorite.

Answer (score 6):

"Frickin'" As in

> Sharks with Frickin' Laser Beams
>   attached to their Frickin' Heads

Comment: HAHA. Austin powers reference

Answer (score 5):

Since I watched Battlestar Galactica (the new series), I've been using '[frakking](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Frak)' a lot.

Comment: I hated that word, but +1 for Galactica :-)

Answer (score 5):

Any substitute sounds contrived and ridiculous.  If you don't want to swear, simply don't.  E.g.:

> "I think Homer Simpson is incredibly
>   sexy"
>
> My reply "Get out of here! That's
>   ridiculous."

You see?  Just as effective.

Comment: What's wrong with sounding contrived and/or ridiculous?

Answer (score 2):

French Connection UK has made a brand out of their substitute.

[image]

Comment: [German company took advantage from it more directly having won the right for brand "Fucking Beer"](http://www.spiegel.de/international/zeitgeist/0,1518,686305,00.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since watching the movie [Fantastic Mr. Fox](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0432283/) I have been enamoured with [*cussing*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJP31ZiUgeM).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that's easy. Just substitute your least liked bread. I often scream "corn bread!" when I'm frustrated. Some people go with biscuits. Nice thing about English is you can add suffix "ing" to anything.

Comment: or even "bread basket"

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUBAR

Update:
Verbally I prefer French [foutu](http://translate.google.com/#fr|en|foutu).
It is, by the way, printable word. One can find it in lyrics, for example, in
[Le Temps Des Cathédrales - Bruno Pelletier - Notre-Dame de Paris (comédie musicale)](http://musique.ados.fr/Notre-Dame-De-Paris/Le-Temps-Des-Cathedrales-Bruno-Pelletier-t99643.html)

In internet (chat, twitter, Email) I usually give/insert the link to multi-media ["Polar Bear"](http://goo.gl/iT2aq)

See also my related question  ["How would you substitute English vulgar words in foreign phrases?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15232/how-would-you-substitute-english-vulgar-words-in-foreign-phrases)

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of @mvexel's response I use frakking, but before Battlestar Galatica there was [Farscape](http://www.farscape.com), and from it I took "[frelling](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Frell)" which I use more than "frakking" or the original.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JasonFruit's answer, and will add another option:

> Get out of here! That's completely ridiculous.

The word *completely* works here, though not in all contexts. Having to think of an appropriate adverb (or, sometimes, other word) in a given context will provide good exercise for your brain.

Comment: or _absolutely_ (I think I like _completely_ better though)