# How would you substitute English vulgar words in foreign phrases?

Tags: synonyms, offensive-language

Subquestioning ["Substitute for F*** in emphasizing disbelief, anger, etc"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14861/substitute-for-f-in-emphasizing-disbelief-anger-etc):
How would you substitute the vulgar English word in foreign phrases like in:
1) brand name:
 ["Fucking beer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUt0S.jpg)?

or
2)in village name

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't.  Bowdlerizing actual foreign names because of English-speaker squeamishness is just over so many lines, for me.  If people are in a situation where they need to discuss Fucking, Austria, they just need to learn to deal with it.

Besides, if we can learn to handle Bangkok, we can handle anything.

Comment: Well said. I grew up in a French village who's French name is the feminine of cat, but is also slang for “pussy”. Clearly, this lead to a lot of not-overly-subtle-jokes in high school, but most of the children survived.

Comment: @F'x: I do presume that those children claimed millions from the municipality for prolonged psychiatric therapy?